# How can I solve the AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'distance'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, attributeerror

I am trying to write a Snake game using Turtle graphics but getting the attribute error. How can I fix this?

Error:

> AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'distance.'

#### This is my main.py

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import turtle
import time
from snake import Snake
from food import Food

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("My snake game")
screen.tracer(0)


snake = Snake()
food = Food()

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(snake.up, "Up")
screen.onkey(snake.down, "Down")
screen.onkey(snake.right, "Right")
screen.onkey(snake.left, "Left")

snake.create_turtle()

is_game_on = True
while is_game_on:
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    snake.move()

    #detect collision with food
    if snake.head.distance(food) < 15:
        food.refresh()
    
    
    
screen.exitonclick()
```

#### This is my snake.py

```
from turtle import Turtle
X_POSITION = [0, -20, -40]
MOVE_POSITION = 20
UP = 90
DOWN = 270
LEFT = 180
RIGHT = 0

class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.turtle_list = []
        self.create_turtle()
        self.move()
    
    def create_turtle(self):
        for turtle_index in range(0, 3):
            new_turtle = Turtle(shape="square")
            new_turtle.color("white")
            new_turtle.penup()
            new_turtle.goto(x=X_POSITION[turtle_index],y=0)
            self.turtle_list.append(new_turtle)



    def move(self):
        for seg in range(len(self.turtle_list) -1, 0, -1):  #(same as start= 2, stop= 0, step= 1):
            new_x = self.turtle_list[seg -1].xcor()
            new_y = self.turtle_list[seg -1].ycor()
            self.turtle_list[seg].goto(x=new_x, y=new_y) 
        self.turtle_list[0].forward(MOVE_POSITION)
    
    def up(self):
        if self.turtle_list[0].heading() != DOWN:
            self.turtle_list[0].setheading(UP)
    
    def down(self):
        if self.turtle_list[0].heading() != UP:
            self.turtle_list[0].setheading(DOWN)

    def left(self):
        if self.turtle_list[0].heading() != RIGHT:
            self.turtle_list[0].setheading(LEFT)

    def right(self):
        if self.turtle_list[0].heading() != LEFT:
            self.turtle_list[0].setheading(RIGHT)
```

#### This is my food.py

```
from turtle import Turtle, circle
import random

class Food(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("circle")
        self.shapesize(stretch_len=0.5, stretch_wid=0.5)
        self.penup()
        self.speed("fastest")
        self.color("green")
        self.refresh
        
    
    def refresh(self):
        random_x = random.randint(-280, 280)
        random_y = random.randint(-280, 280)
        self.goto(random_x,random_y)
```

How can I check the attribute error stated above?

Comment: The error doesn't seem to match the code provided: we'd expect `AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'head'` with that code.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: My bad, I did not mention snake.head as snake.turtle_list[0] in snake.py. 

Now I just changed to the below code, and it worked. 

```
if snake.turtle_list[0].distance(food) < 15:
        food.refresh()
```

Thanks for looking into this @slothrop and @Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

snake.head was not mentioned in the snake.py for snake.turtle_list[0].

The below code worked.

```
 if snake.turtle_list[0].distance(food) < 15: 
       food.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your definition of the snake class to this:

```
class Snake(Turtle):
    
     def __init__(self):
        
          super().__init__()
```

The '(Turtle)' means it will inherit from the turtle class. This means you have forgotten to inherit from the turtle class.

If that doesn't fix the problem, try this:

```
if snake.turtle_list[0].distance(food) < 15:

     food.refresh()
```

If the second one works, most likely you have forgotten to define the head in `snake.head`

Comment: Hi Ria, Thanks for your response. 
Turtle inheritance is not required for the snake class. However, the second one works. I certainly did forget to define snake.head with the snake.turtle_list[0]